St_nearest_point
I have two dataframe with coordination values, I want to match each point of my dataset2 with the nearest point in my dataset1, then use its value.
I tried transfered them into sf object then using st_nearest_point function,but that gives me back std::bad_alloc. I checked by justing using one point then I get a large sfc object. Do I have anyother way to find the nearest points?

For coding questions, please provide a code snippet of what you have tried.

You probably want st_nearest_feature.
Make sample data, ten points with z column A to J and 26 points with z column a to z:
p1 = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=runif(10), y=runif(10),z=LETTERS[1:10]), coords=1:2)
p2 = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=runif(26), y=runif(26),z=letters), coords=1:2)

Get nearest features:
nn = st_nearest_feature(p1, p2)

nn is an index, so if we want the z value from nearest p2 added to our p1 values:
p1$NN = p2$z[nn]

Giving:
> p1
Simple feature collection with 10 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0.01338362 ymin: 0.08187369 xmax: 0.980123 ymax: 0.9803208
CRS:           NA
   z                     geometry NN
1  A   POINT (0.980123 0.1645394)  z
2  B  POINT (0.8833199 0.3746011)  z
3  C  POINT (0.4774583 0.9803208)  h
4  D POINT (0.7467349 0.08497843)  e
5  E  POINT (0.01743261 0.213194)  m
6  F POINT (0.1652479 0.08187369)  x
7  G  POINT (0.5864398 0.2617177)  u
8  H POINT (0.05017561 0.6214134)  p
9  I POINT (0.01338362 0.3490553)  l
10 J  POINT (0.7226854 0.7183099)  k

Here NN is the z value of the point in p2 nearest the point given in p1.

Yeah finally I used st_nearest_feature, but still confused how do people use st_nearest_points, what this function returns is actually not a point

st_nearest_points is useful for things like "for each point in p1, where's the nearest point of each polygon in poly2".  So if you have 10 cities and 50 states you get back 500 features, lines from each of the 10 cities to the nearest point on every state boundary, which is useful. But if you have 10 cities and 50 points (eg state capitals) you still get 500 features, a line for each city to each capital, because the nearest point of a point is always the point, which is less useful.  Its always pairwise over the two parameters.
